# Alternatives To Viewport Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, blackberry

I am creating an application that will be used via a web browser control in a blackberry native application. In the blackberry browser the application responds as expected by in the native applications browser control it is very slow. It seems that the major performance cost is this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If I take this out the application runs fine but for obvious reasons its not scaled correctly. What is the best way to find an alternative for this (if there is one)? I am only focusing on bleckberry applications no other mobile devices, is there something I could try to bypass this , but still maintain the scaling of the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other option to it is to redetect the Operating System, browser, or Phone as a blackberry.  Then you need to create another site, which is totally different from a desktop site or a mobile site. A Blackberry has a totally different style/css support.

Here is the information depending on the software version that Blackberry supports:

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/Feature_CSS_512751_11.jsp

You can also check on the fundamentals how they support tables, images, forms and media streaming on the page's sidebar.